# how to load data into datagridview from a List<>

Tags: c#

pls  help i am newbie in C# my problem is i defined my class laoded  into customerList (name, last name, address and so..on )my problem is i have a form with datagridview (custDGV) and trying to laod into it  here is my code

```
 private void listCustomer_Frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView custDGV = new DataGridView();
            customerList = CustomerDB.GetListCustomer();
            custDGV.DataSource = customerList;
            cm = (CurrencyManager)custDGV.BindingContext[customerList];
            cm.Refresh();
        }
```

when i run it shows blank.  if some  has the patients to tell me what i need to do

Comment: Take a look at this to see how to bind to the datagridview in detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: customerList is a list<string> right?

Answer (score 0):

is anyone have good experience deal with DataGridView  my issue is that i have loaded into my customerList when i debuged i can see all the 10 records but when comes to  the form to load into  the DataGridView does not load here its the code

```
private void listCustomer_Frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView custDGV = new DataGridView();
    customerList = CustomerDB.GetListCustomer();
    custDGV.DataSource = customerList;
    cm = (CurrencyManager)custDGV.BindingContext[customerList];
    cm.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: BindingSource customerBindingSource = new BindingSource();
                customerList = CustomerDB.GetListCustomer();
                customerBindingSource.DataSource = customerList;
                custDGV.DataSource = customerBindingSource;
                //custDGV.DataSource = typeof(customerList);
                //customerBindingSource.DataMember = "Customer";
                //cm = (CurrencyManager)customerBindingSource.BindingContext[customerList];
                //cm.Refresh();